# Java/Android absolute fastest way to periodically get current seconds (0-59) and/or milliseconds (0-999)

Tags: java, android

I'm executing a `Runnable` within an Android application every 100ms wrapped in a Java `ScheduledExecutorService`. As a part of the `run()` block I need to obtain the current seconds as 0-59 and milliseconds as 0-999. Both should be in local time, although UTC is workable too.

What's the **absolute fastest** way to do this? Internationalization/unique calendars aren't required.

Currently I'm using `Calendar` in the below way, but I was thinking it could be faster to use `System.currentTimeMillis()` and do some math, I'd appreciate any input.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

If it's relevant, this is actually within an Android application.

**Edit for clarification**

Obtaining the current seconds as 0-59 (i.e. relative to the current minute) is critical, so `System.currentTimeMillis()` comes with a math cost as I mentioned above. What I wasn't sure about was whether doing this math + the system call would be faster than the call to `Calendar`, or if there are any other options (like [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)) which may have even less of a footprint.

For reference, below is the most straightforward way I could come up with off the top of my head to get seconds (0-59) from the Unix timestamp.

```
double seconds = Math.floor(((Math.floor(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) % 86400) % 3600) % 60);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't find *anything* faster than `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

That said, fast and correct don't necessarily go hand-in-hand. As always: consider using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). You're just not going to be able to hit all the edge cases correctly without a library.

Comment: Right, that's a very good point. Please see my edit for clarification about the specifics. Is System.currentTimeMillis() + math absolutely the fastest? This is a very targeted use-case, so I believe a time library wouldn't be a good fit unless it calculates current seconds (0-59) and milliseconds (0-999) faster than Calendar. The only edge case I need to account for is if there are not 86400 seconds in a day, so perhaps it is possible the UTC leap second could cause an issue that a time library would solve?

Comment: For correctness you need to account for UTC leap seconds. You said UTC is workable, which does mean that you're a little closer than if you need local time - if you actually do want correct local time, really just use a library. There are **many** edge cases as soon as you need local (non-UTC) time. Have you found this is really a bottleneck in your code at all? I don't understand the resistance to using the library; time is _very_ easy to get wrong.

Comment: great video! I will use a time library for any additional time calculations. As I mentioned in my question though I'm still simply trying to discern which method is the most lightweight, not an analysis of when I should use a time library for time (always).